# Hibernate not generating foreign keys in database

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

I created a many to one relationship between my tables Person and adress it appears to be created given my ER diagram. But it's not making anything happen in my datasource, no join no

Is there a way to make this happen or is it supposed to be like that for Intellij? Seems to be easy to do with Eclipse.

This is my code for both entities and anything I think is relevant,  don't hesitate to ask if you need anything.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "personne", schema = "bddpersistence")
@IdClass(PersonneEntityPK.class)
public class PersonneEntity {
    private int idPersonne;
    private String nom;
    private String prenom;
    private String email;
    private String tel;
    private Integer age;
    private Integer idAdress;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "personne",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<AdressEntity> adress = new ArrayList<AdressEntity>();
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "adress", schema = "bddpersistence")
public class AdressEntity {
    private String rue;
    private Integer codePostal;
    private String ville;
    private int idAdress;

    @ManyToOne
    PersonneEntity personne;
```

---

```
package com.example;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Timestamp;


public class TestHibernate {

    static EntityManagerFactory emf;
    static EntityManager em;
    static EntityTransaction transaction;

    public static void beginConnection(){

        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("NewPersistenceUnit");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
        transaction = em.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();

    }

    public static void endConnection(){

        transaction.commit();
        em.close();
        emf.close();

    }

    public static void insertAccount(String email, String name){
        ComptesEntity compte = new ComptesEntity();
        compte.setEmail(email);
        compte.setNom(name);
        em.persist(compte);
    }

    public static void createPerson (int id_personne,String nom,String prenom,int age,String email,String tel,String rue,String cp,String ville){

    }

    public static void insertPerson(String lastName, String firstName , String email, String tel , int age){
        PersonneEntity personne = new PersonneEntity();
        personne.setNom(lastName);
        personne.setPrenom(firstName);
        personne.setTel(tel);
        personne.setEmail(email);
        personne.setAge(age);
        em.persist(personne);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        beginConnection();
        endConnection();
    }
}
```

Here is the persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd"
             version="2.2">

    <persistence-unit name="NewPersistenceUnit">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bddpersistence"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="kamoulox369"/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And here is the hibernate config :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bddpersistence</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping class="com.example.AdressEntity"/>
    <mapping resource="com/example/AdressEntity.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping class="com.example.ClubEntity"/>
    <mapping resource="com/example/ClubEntity.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping class="com.example.ComptesEntity"/>
    <mapping resource="com/example/ComptesEntity.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping class="com.example.ParticipationEntity"/>
    <mapping resource="com/example/ParticipationEntity.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping class="com.example.PersonneEntity"/>
    <mapping resource="com/example/PersonneEntity.hbm.xml"/>

    <!-- <property name="connection.username"/> -->
    <!-- <property name="connection.password"/> -->

    <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
    <!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> -->
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Lastly the composite PK for PersonEntity :

```
package com.example;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

public class PersonneEntityPK implements Serializable {
    private int idPersonne;
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "id_personne")
    @Id
    public int getIdPersonne() {
        return idPersonne;
    }

    public void setIdPersonne(int idPersonne) {
        this.idPersonne = idPersonne;
    }

    @Column(name = "email")
    @Id
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        PersonneEntityPK that = (PersonneEntityPK) o;
        return idPersonne == that.idPersonne &&
                Objects.equals(email, that.email);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(idPersonne, email);
    }
}
```

I left out part of the code for entity that was just generated like the getters and setters.

Comment: I think you should annotate the appropriate field with @Id in the class `PersonneEntity ` and what does the field idAdress mean in that class? What do you mean with "it does not anything happen"?

Comment: I meant that it's not creating the link in database , not creating the join , the foreign key or anything that's related to the creation of this relationship. I'm using the same code as my fellow students but they are on eclipse for that and I'm wondering if I can do the same with Intellij.

Comment: I have an indicator that the link is made between the entities on the diagram of the persistence unit , but not between the tables in the datasource

Comment: For the idAdress I actually deleted it , I wanted to make a join on it , but apparently it's supposed to make a link from the adress table with the fields from the PersonPK

Comment: The creation of the tables is not related to the IDE (Eclipse or IntelliJ). The persistence unit does this for you. So I don't think it is related to the IDE rather to some configuration of your application server. What application server do you use and what tables and columns are actually created in your DB?

Comment: I'm actually not using an application server atm , just connecting to a datasource that was premade , so the tables were already made and the entities were generated automatically , I didn't find a way to create the tables from the entities , and actually came across some info saying that Intellij wouldn't allow me to generate tables from an entity that I create myself. Is it false ? I think I need to find a good in depth tutorial or course for hibernate ahah. There is too much stuff I don't get yet